# pgfplots: How to clip the decorated path to the viewport limits and make 'text align' use its new limits?

Tags: pgfplots, decorations

Without the need to explicitly set the x-domain key `domain`, how to clip the decorated path to the viewport y-limits `ymin = 0.5, ymax = 2.5` so that `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` is what can be measured on the screen?

In other words, `text align = {left indent = {0.75\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}}` should typeset the text `text` in nearly the bottom right corner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, math, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0.5, ymax = 2.5,
            ]
            %
            \addplot [
                    variable = \Fbr,
                    postaction = {
                        decoration = {
                            text along path,
                            text = {text},
                            text align = {left indent = {0.75\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}},
                            }, decorate,
                        },
                    ] {1 - \Fbr};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `clip=false`, and `standalone`, you can see where your text goes:

[image]

the line is built using the default domain (-5:5) and then clipped.

Maybe you want the following (I restricted the domain of the plot):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, math, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0.5, ymax = 2.5,
            domain = -1.5:0.5,
            % clip=false,
            ]
            %
            \addplot [
                    variable = \Fbr,
                    postaction = {
                        decoration = {
                            text along path,
                            text = {text},
                            text align = {left indent = {0.75\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}},
                            }, decorate,
                        },
                    ] {1 - \Fbr};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to specify just the vertical domain and let the rest go alone, you should plot [using y as a variable](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-addplot#sec-14.3):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, math, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain = 2.5:0.5,
            ]
            %
            \addplot [
                    variable = \Fbr,
                    postaction = {
                        decoration = {
                            text along path,
                            text = {text},
                            text align = {left indent = {0.75\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}},
                            }, decorate,
                        },
                        ] ({1 - \Fbr}, \Fbr);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...but you need a domain; it is where `pgfplots` iterates to find the function points.

PD: I imagine yours is just an example and you are using decorations because you need them in more complex plots, because otherwise:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain = 2.5:0.5,
            ]
            %
            \addplot [variable=\Fbr] ({1 - \Fbr}, \Fbr) node[above, sloped, pos=0.75]{text};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives almost the same output:

[image]

Comment: I don't need to set `domain = -1.5:0.5`. I need it to be similarly done somehow implicitly based on my input of `ymin = 0.5, ymax = 2.5`.

Comment: The only way that could work is plotting in function of `y` instead of `x`. Otherwise, I don't think that `pgfplots` is able to infer the domain using the ordinate (result) axis.